# Paths to specific project in trigger not working when triggered from a branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We currently use Azure DevOps for our builds and have set up triggers for branches. We have a solution that contains multiple projects. To build a spefic project, we have included "paths" to include the project in the build.

However, when a build is triggered from a branch that is not the master branch, all projects are built. When triggering directly from the master branch, only the specific project is built (as expected).

Is there a way to set the "Paths: Include:" to build just the specific project for all branches?

YAML code for the trigger:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - bugfix/*
    - task/*
    - feature/*
  paths:
    include:
    - '/Project1'
```

Comment: What is your build task? the triggers section it's only for what will trigger the build, not which projects will be built.

Comment: I am confused about the operation of how to make all  projects built while trigger from a branch.